# Maven: jar-with-dependencies + JavaDoc

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project that has a few dependencies on other Jars. I currently use the JavaDoc plugin and Assembly plugin to generate a .zip of my project, which contains my Jar, the dependency Jars, plus the javadoc.

However, I would like to boil things down so that there is only a single Jar inside the .zip, along with the relevant JavaDoc. I know that the assembly plugin + jar-with-dependencies is my friend for this, but how do I work it out such that I can package up a .zip containing this jar, along with my JavaDoc?

Relevant parts of my pom below:

```
  <properties>
    <assemblyJar>${project.build.finalName}.jar</assemblyJar>
    <assemblyJwd>${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</assemblyJwd>
    <java.code.version>1.4</java.code.version>
  </properties>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version> <!-- 2.3 might be needed -->
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/dist-jwd.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
      <id>make-jwd</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version> <!-- 2.3 might be needed -->
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/dist.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
      <id>make-zip</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Relevant parts of dist-jwd.xml:

```
<id>dist-jwd</id>

  <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>

  <files>
    <file>
      <fileMode>444</fileMode>
      <source>target/${assemblyJar}</source>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
    </file>
  </files>

  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>javax.servlet:servlet-api</exclude>
      </excludes>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
```

And relevant parts of dist.xml:

```
<id>dist-zip</id>

  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>

  <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>

  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <fileMode>444</fileMode>
      <directory>target/site/apidocs</directory>
      <outputDirectory>javadoc</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>

  <files>
    <file>
      <fileMode>444</fileMode>
      <source>target/${assemblyJwd}</source>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
    </file>
  </files>
```

Currently I get the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.1:single (make-jwd) on project deviceinsight-api-java: Failed to create assembly: Error adding file to archive: /Users/barmistead/Mercurial/deviceinsight-print/target/deviceinsight-api-java-3.1.16-1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar isn't a file. -> [Help 1]
```

I'm guessing this is a possible chicken-and-egg problem, so If maven doesn't have a graceful solution then I will have to do something manually. However, I think what I'm trying to do is pretty common, so I would think there would be an easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up giving up and running a .sh script after the maven stuff to do what I wanted.

Unix to the rescue!